# Display computation of BMI in another activity in android

Tags: android

**Hello I'm just new in android ..I just wanna ask if how can I display a computation of BMI from Menu Window to another activity called Register Window in android..because when I run this code no display of result in register window..  thank you**

****Register Window ****

---

```
  public void onClick(View v)
    {   
        Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, Menu.class);
            intent.putExtra("response","counter");
            startActivity(intent);   

        int weight = 0, height = 0, age = 0, answer = 0;
        String test1, test2, test3;
        test1 = getString(R.id.tvWeight);
        test2 = getString(R.id.tvAge);
        test3 = getString(R.id.tvHeight);

        try {
            if (test1 != "" && test2 != "" && test3 != "") {
                Eweight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvWeight);
                weight = Integer.parseInt(Eweight.getText().toString().trim());
                Eage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvAge);
                age = Integer.parseInt(Eage.getText().toString().trim());
                Eheight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tvHeight);
                height = Integer.parseInt(Eheight.getText().toString().trim());

                if(gender.contains("Male"))
                    answer = (int) Math.round(1.2 * (66 + (13.7 * weight) + (5 * height) - (6.8 * age)));

                if(gender.contains("Female"))
                    answer = (int) Math.round(1.2*(655 + (9.6 * weight) + (1.8 * height) - (4.7 * age)));

                response = answer + " kcal/day";
                counter.setText(response);


            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }
```

**Menu Window**

```
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Intent intent = getIntent();
                intent.getStringExtra("response");

                String answer = intent.getStringExtra(response);


            }
        });
```

Comment: No need to launch a new `Activity` just for that. Just change the current layout if you want to change what's being shown (`setContentView`).

Comment: but it is required to show the result to the other activity because in my project ..example when a user inputs his/her age,weight and height then he/she click submit in Register window it will appear "Success!" then it will automatically compute and proceed to the Menu Window to display the result of BMI

Comment: Let me try to explain again: you don't need a **new** `Activity` just to change the layout (what's being shown). If you want to do it in a new Activity anyway, [go ahead](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29). You can use the `Bundle` to pass anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

Difficult to answer in detail because you don't provide enough details, e.g. what's `gender`?

You don't need a new `Activity` just to change the layout (what's being shown). Just do what you want to do in the `onClick()` method (including layout change).

If you want to do it in a new `Activity` anyway, you need to use [`startActivityForResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29). You can use the `Bundle` (3rd parameter) to pass anything you want to the new `Activity`. Keep in mind that when this new *child* `Activity` ends, the caller's [`onActivityResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) will be called, not next sentence in the code like you seem to believe here:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, Menu.class);
    intent.putExtra("response","counter");
    startActivity(intent);   

    int weight = 0, height = 0, age = 0, answer = 0;
    String test1, test2, test3;
    test1 = getString(R.id.tvWeight);
    test2 = getString(R.id.tvAge);
    test3 = getString(R.id.tvHeight);
```

PS: in Java, only class/interface names start with upper-case. Class fields start with lower-case.